# How to handle HTTP status in Angular HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular

I use addition option for POST request :

```
 return this.http.post("", data, { observe: "response" });
```

When I try to handle this response in interceptor, I can not get http status:

```
 return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
          console.log(event.status);
      return event;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to observe response actually. You may remove { observe: "response" }. 
All what you need to handle it in interceptor is add catchError to pipe. To escape from error **(if you want request to finish with success)** you should return Observable of something in catchError.
Also you can notify user or perform some actions on certain errors like Klodian showed above.

```
 return next.handle(request).pipe(
 catchError(error => {
   if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
   // notify user or perfome actions
   }

   return of([]);   // return empty Observable of array 
  }),
  map((event: any) => {
      console.log(event.status);
  return event;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use catchError inside pipe like this below:

```
 .pipe(
       catchError(err => { // catch response error from server
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                  switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>err).status) {
                     case 401: // if is 401 error
                  }
             }

       })
  );
```

Comment: @OPV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes - I arrived there by searching with the exact text of your comment. That said, it depends on your BE's implementation. Some APIs return 200 for everything (which is not standard, but people do it).